# How to integrate over pandas data frame with non constant Jacobin

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, integration

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this:

```
E     p     S
.1   .1     4
.1.  .2     5
.    .      .
.    .      .
.3   .1     2
.3.  .2     4
.    .      .
.    .      .
15.  .1     5
15.  .2     9
.    .      .
.    .      .
```

As you see for each value of `E` there are multiple values of `p` and `S`. I'm trying to numerically perform the integral `$n(E) = \Int dp p^2 S$` for each value of E. Unfortunately due to the `p^2` factor in the integral I don't think I can use `groupby(['E']).sum()` because that will only perform the sum over `S` without the `p^2` factor. Any way to do this integral in a nice pythonic way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [numpy's trapezoidal formula](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) you can do:

```
df.groupby('E').apply(lambda x: np.trapz(x['S'].mul(x['p']**2), x['p']))
```